# drainage problem from kitchen sink

Tags: plumbing, drainage

My kitchen sink(double sink) backs up, there is no clog I have removed the trap, I have also removed the basement trap and snaked both ways. Now the bathroom sink will also backup at same time, so I cut the pipe where I thought the sink drain runs, snaked it and rejoined. Things were good for a while but sink is backing up again and when I run dishwasher it backs up the sink and water pools at the bottom of dishwasher all the while creating a raining of water under the sink down into basement?!

Comment: It's really difficult to troubleshoot a problem like this through the internet. It could be a clog somewhere down the line, a plugged vent, or improper plumbing. All of which can only be discovered by being there.